# How do I link a html form with a sql databse table?

Tags: php, mysql, html, phpmyadmin

I have XAMPP running. I have a HTML form page that takes input from users (this file is saved with .php extension in htdocs). Upon clicking submit I want all the data in the forms to be saved in a table I created in mySQL ( Iam using phpmyadmin).How can I go about doing this?

Comment: what did you try ?

Comment: I am looking up turorials on php and mysql to figure it out. Iam not going anywhere though....!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a new page process.php
make html form action attribute to process.php

```
<form action="process.php" method="post">
```

in process.php

```
$field1 = $_POST['field1'];
$field2 = $_POST['field2'];
```

Repeat this for all your form fields and then use sql to save data to table

```
mysqli_connect('host','username','password','databasename');
$sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO table_name VALUES ('%s','%s',...)",$field1,$field2,...);
```

both %s and variables number and position match.

```
mysqli_query($sql);
```

That should do...

```
if(isset($_POST['formSubmit'])){
  $cardNO= $_POST['cardNO'];
  $employeeNO= $_POST['employeeNO'];
  $employeename= $_POST['employeename'];
  $nationality= $_POST['nationality'];
  $profession= $_POST['profession'];
  $DOB= $_POST['DOB'];
  $DOJ= $_POST['DOJ'];
  $DOA= $_POST['DOA'];
  $companycode = $_POST['companycode'];
  $sponsorcode= $_POST['sponsorcode'];
  $visatype= $_POST['visatype'];
  $status= $_POST['status'];
  mysqli_connect('host','username','password','databasename');
  $sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO table_name(col1,col2,col3,...) VALUES ('','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s')",$cardNO,$employeeNO,$employeename,$nationality,$profession,$DOB,$DOJ,$DOA,$companycode,$sponsorcode,$visatype,$status);
  mysqli_query($sql);
}
```

Code for process.php

Sorry for the delayed Replay

Comment: Thank you. I will study your method in detail and incorporate it if suitable.

Comment: @gotham This is the simplest method I can offer. If you provided html form I could give accurate code for it..

Comment: @gothem Sry for delayed replay and since i don't know your database table the sql is not perfect.. please replace col1,col2,col3... with your table column names... Note:-First empty string is indended for your table id which will auto increment...(if you have one :) )

Comment: Thank you. Also is there a default username and password for mysql. Is it compulsory to set one? Is it possible to skip authentication part?

Comment: After making the required changes i ran my fomrs page. Upon clicking submit a new page opened displaying the following:

Comment: @gotham you cannot skip the authentication part... It's certain that there is a username and its root by default... Password would be ''(empty string) by default. It opens new page but doesn't display a thing here. If you want to go to another page after this process is completed use header function of php after mysqli_query

Comment: If you keep using mysqli_connect on mutiple pages it's better to put it on another file db.php and include it on the pages that you want to use it on.

Answer (score 0):

Direct answer, there is no api with phpmyadmin that you can use for the same.
So how do you do that,

First you need to make a form that corresponds to all the data fields in database and post to the PHP file. Once that is done you will have a frontend form that you can use to recieve the data from the user. Now comes the part where you actually feed the data to the database.

Use $_POST variable to iterate through form data in PHP script and connect to MYSQL database using PDO drivers in PHP. Now you can write mysql queries from PHP. Based on data from $_POST create an insert query that you can use and fill it with data and execute the query. Now the PHP script will connect to database and insert the data from the form. The data then would be visible inside Phpmyadmin also.

**Note**

Although i am pretty sure that Phpmyadmin has an api for inseting data but that is not recommended because that will open your entire database to public. Phpmyadmin is pretty powerfull and can also be used to delete your entire database

Comment: Thank you. I will do more research based on your valuable inputs. Once again thank you very much......

Comment: @Gotham accept the answer then :) and if you have any other problem just comment here, happy to help

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<body>

<form name="EmployeeDatabase" action="Employee.php" method="post">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">

<h1>EMPLOYEE DATABASE</h1>

Employe Card NO: <input type="text" name="cardNO" ><br><br>
Employee NO: <input type="text" name="employeeNO" ><br><br>
Employee Name: <input type="text" name="employeename"><br><br>
Nationality: <input type="text" name="nationality"><br><br>
Profession: <input type="text" name="profession"><br><br>
DOB: <input type="text" name="DOB"><br><br>
DOJ: <input type="text" name="DOJ"><br><br>
DOA(VisitVisa): <input type="text" name="DOA"><br><br>
Company Code: <input type="text" name="companycode"><br><br>
Sponsor Code: <input type="text" name="sponsorcode"><br><br>
Visa Type: <input type="text" name="visatype"><br><br>
Status: <input type="text" name="status"><br><br>

<input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Submit">

<?php

?>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```